# Using parameter of generic type in generic method of interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

my friends. I'm new to generics, but want to create interface (let it be IFooAsync) with generic method (FooAsync) that gets parameter of another generic type (that has definition Process), but I don't want to include this U type in method definition. How to do that right? My code now looks like this (I've used Object as generic Progress type, but sure it's an awful solution):

```cs
public interface IFooAsync
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<T>> FooAsync<T>(
        // Some parameters, that my method gonna take.
        System.IProgress<Object> progress,
        System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : new();
}
```

Comment: *Why* don't you want to include `U` in the method definition? If you want it to actually be an `IProgress<U>` (I'd recommend actually calling it `TProgress`) then it feels like it would be better to make it a type parameter. How will you use the progress within implementations?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I don't want to use additional parameter like U because it doesn't influence the logic of the method, but parameter of type Progress must be provided to generate feedback to the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface IFooAsync<TReturn> where TReturn : new()
{
    Task<List<TReturn>> FooAsync<TProgress>(IProgress<TProgress> progress, 
                                            CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

which means you don't have to specify two type paremeters when calling the method as the compiler can infer them.

e.g.

```
IFooAsync<string> myFoo = ... ;
IProgress<int> myProgress = ... ;

List<string> result = await myFoo.FooAsync(myProgress, CancellationToken.None);
```